# How to jar java source files from different (sub-)directories?

Tags: java, ant

Consider the following directory structure:

```
./source/com/mypackage/../A.java
./extensions/extension1/source/com/mypackage/../T.java
./extensions/extension2/source/com/mypackage/../U.java
...
./extensions/extensionN/source/com/mypackage/../Z.java
```

I want to produce a source jar with the following contents:

```
com/mypackage/../A.java
com/mypackage/../T.java
com/mypackage/../U.java
...
com/mypackage/../Z.java
```

I know I could use a fileset for each source directory.
But is there an easy solution using ANT without having to refer to all extensions explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about flattening all the files to be included in the archive into a single directory structure, then archiving from there?

Use a [regexpmapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) to do the flatten during copy, something like this:

```
<delete dir="merged" />
<mkdir dir="merged" />

<copy todir="${basedir}/merged">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="source/**"/>
        <include name="extension*/**"/>
    </fileset>
    <regexpmapper from=".*source/(.*)" to="\1" />
</copy>

<jar destfile="mypackage.jar" filesonly="yes">
    <fileset dir="merged">
        <include name="**" />
    </fileset>
</jar>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Martin. That did the trick.
The regexpmapper was the missing part.
I only had to add the attribute handledirsep="true" to the mapper to make it work on Windows.