# Merge all subdirectories in a single jar

Tags: java, ant

I have a directory structure like this (pretty much standard in Netbeans)

```
src/
build/generated/gen-1
build/generated/gen-2
...
build/generatad/gen-n
```

I'm packaging all the sources in a single jar with the following ant command:

```
<jar destfile="sources.jar" compress="true">
    <fileset dir="src"/>
    <fileset dir="build/generated/gen-1"/>
    <fileset dir="build/generated/gen-2"/>
    ...
    <fileset dir="build/generated/gen-n"/>
</jar>
```

Is there a compact way to say that I want to jar together all the subdirectories of `build/generated`, but avoiding the gen-*i* prefix?

I tried fiddling with `<dirset>`, but was not able to mix it with `<jar>`.

I would like a way which avoids copying everything to a temporary directory (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794365/472393)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have at least Ant 1.8 you can use `<mappedresources>`

```
<jar destfile="sources.jar" compress="true">
    <fileset dir="src"/>
    <mappedresources>
        <fileset dir="build/generated"/>
        <regexpmapper from="^gen-\d*/(.*)$$" to="\1" handledirsep="true"/>
    </mappedresources>
</jar>
```

(note the doubled dollar sign in the `from` attribute, which is actually a single dollar in the regexp due to the way Ant does property expansion in attributes)

Comment: I found out also `<cutdirsmapper dirs="1"/>`, which does the trick with an easier syntax.

Comment: @Flavio so it does, my Ant is 1.8.1 which is why I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible in Ant. You can take a look at [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=build-tools&file=ant) library, but that one also requires all file sets to be specified.

If you have a chance of using another build tool, then I would recommend [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), where it is definitely possible.

Comment: Thanks but switching build system is not an option!